# Melting multiple csv files not working, only melts one of the csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, concatenation

Having issues melting multiple csv files (500) into one csv file. When running the application it creates one csv file as desired but only with one ticker. It seems like that it doesnt iterate through all the stored csv files.
this it what the out put looks like: [CSV output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RbrR.png)

```
    for count, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

    df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker}, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], 1, inplace=True)

    main_df = pd.DataFrame()

    df = df.reset_index()
    df = df.melt(id_vars=['Date'], var_name='Ticker', value_name='Closed')

    main_df = main_df.append(df)

    print(main_df.head())
main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')
```

compile_data()

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by that `if/else` logic there - have you got an `main_df = pd.DataFrame()` somewhere you're supposed to be appending to... can you not just build up one large dataframe, then write that melted to the output?

Comment: You modify `main_df` within your for loop for every ticker (removing any previous values), but export it outside the for loop. Hence, only the final ticker is exported.

Comment: Should the :  main_df = pd.DataFrame()

        df = df.reset_index()
        df = df.melt(id_vars=['Date'], var_name='Ticker', value_name='Closed')

        main_df = main_df.append(df)

        print(main_df.head())
    main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')
be included in the for loop then ? @asongtoruin

Comment: Hey JonClements, I changed it like @Charles R proposed but still only generates one ticker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the if / else, try to instanciate an empty dataframe that you will populate with each melted df.

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame()

for count, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

    df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker}, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], 1, inplace=True)

    df = df.reset_index()
    df = df.melt(id_vars=['Date'], var_name='Ticker', value_name='Closed')

    main_df = main_df.append(df)

    if count % 10 == 0:
        print(count)

print(main_df.head())
main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')
```

Comment: I changed the code to:
 main_df = pd.DataFrame()

        df = df.reset_index()
        df = df.melt(id_vars=['Date'], var_name='Ticker', value_name='Closed')

        main_df = main_df.append(df)

        print(main_df.head())
    main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')

Comment: But still only taking the last csv file

Comment: Have you put a print inside the for loop to get shure it actualy find several files ?

Comment: I did update the answer lately. Did you use the new one ?